# Imprimir interfaz gráfica de formulario en Java

Tags: java, java-swing, impresión, impresora

Deseo imprimir el `JFrame` al pulsar el botón *IMPRIMIR* en una impresora ( he investigado que para ello se usa la clase PrinterJob ).

¿Se puede imprimir un `JFrame` o `JDialog` tal cual (con el dibujo de la interfaz gracias a **`PrinterJob`**)?

Este **código** lo he probado pero no es de mi utilidad:

```
//Un ejemplo de esta clase puede ser:
public class MiPrintable implements Printable 
{
   public int print (Graphics g, PageFormat f, int pageIndex) 
   {
      if (pageIndex == 0) 
      {
         // Imprime "Hola mundo" en la primera pagina, en la posicion 100,100
         g.drawString("Hola mundo", 100,100);
         return PAGE_EXISTS;
      }
      else
         return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
   }
}
//Una vez que tenemos preparada la clase, sólo hay que pasársela a un PrinterJob y mandarla imprimir. Esto se hace así
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
job.setPrintable( new MiPrintable());
try 
{
   job.print();
} 
catch (PrinterException e) 
{
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Simplemente se obtiene el `PrinterJob` con `PrinterJob.getPrinterJob()`, se le pasa el `Printable` con `job.setPrintable()` y se manda imprimir con `job.print()`.

Imagen que deseo imprimir: [Imagen](https://s27.postimg.org/av5xkcvoj/Captura_de_pantalla_2017_01_09_a_las_10_51_07.png)

Comment: ...¿alguna idea?

Comment: No puedo ver tu imágen porque está bloqueado el sitio desde mi trabajo, por favor edita tu pregunta y sube la imágen a este sitio

Answer (score 1):

como te habrás dado cuenta `Printable` tiene su método para dibujar `print` que recibe una configuración gráfica; los componentes de Swing funcionan de la misma manera.

He escrito un [artículo al respecto](https://javapro.org/programming-languages/java-imprimir-jframe/), pero a continuación pongo las partes esenciales.

Así que lo primero que debes hacer es que tu componente que contenga lo que quieras imprimir implemente la interfaz `Printable` y para cumplir con esa especificación define el método `print`

```
@Override
public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
```

Si detectamos más de una hoja regresamos un flag

```
  if (pageIndex > 0) {
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
  }
```

Ahora para facilitar que la magia suceda, es conveniente usar el API de Java2D, la que nos conviene ya que cuenta con transformaciones afines.

```
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;
```

Luego movemos la parte imprimible a las coordenadas de la impresión visible en nuestra impresora

```
    g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());
```

Escalamos lo que vamos a pintar

```
    g2d.scale(pageFormat.getImageableWidth() / this.getWidth(), pageFormat.getImageableHeight() / this.getHeight());
```

Ahora le dejas todo el trabajo a Swing para encargarse de renderizar en tu dispositivo

```
    this.printAll(g2d);
```

Finalmente le lanzas una bandera para indicar que el contenido guardado debe de ser impreso.

```
    return PAGE_EXISTS;
```

Bueno ¿Y cómo se llama a ese método desde un botón? con un action listener

```
private void botonImprimirInterfazActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    job.setPrintable(this);
    boolean doPrint = job.printDialog(); // mostrar diálogo de impresión
    if (doPrint) {
        try {
            job.setJobName("Nombre a mostrar en la cola de impresión");
            job.print();
        } catch (PrinterException e) {
            // aquí maneja los errores al imprimir
        }
    }
}
```

el escucha de acciones se lo agregas al botón al crearlo.

Answer (score 0):

si lo que queres es que al presionar una tecla genere un evento algo que podes hacer es el metodo `.setMnemonic('tecla');` para que al apretar la <kbd>alt</kbd>+la para activar una funcion

Comment: igual estoy empezando en esto no estoy muy seguro

Comment: Por favor, proporciona detalles adicionales en tu respuesta. Tal como está escrita actualmente, es difícil entender tu solución.