# ¿Cómo imprimir desde Java utilizando la impresora Brother QL-800?

Tags: java, impresión

Estoy creando un editor de etiquetas en java y he escuchado que la impresoras brother utilizan el lenguaje esc/p para imprimir elementos de texto, imágenes, etc.

Necesito ayuda para mandarle los comandos esc/pos a la brother y que esta los reconozca.

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir el código de lo que has intentado?

Comment: Giovani, preguntas demasiadas cosas, y muchas de ellas no son necesarias saberlas para imprimir en Java, según este documento: https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/A16egAjLzES.pdf  no soporta esc/p, sino solamente raw printing o raster printing, es decir algunos de estos https://github.com/qzind/tray/wiki/2.0-Raw-Printing

Comment: El más común de ellos es ESC/POS, no hay ninguna magia, solamente es saber usar los caracteres de escape de esta manera: https://github.com/qzind/tray/wiki/2.0-Raw-Printing#escpos

Comment: Ahora para imprimir, depende mucho lo que quieras imprimir, si solamente texto o gráficos, te recomiendo revisar los códigos de esta pregunta para saber como Java maneja a alto nivel los dos casos mediante una abstracción de gráficos: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43056/printerjob-c%C3%B3mo-imprimir-pantalla-jframe-java-swing/232754#232754

Comment: Igual te recomiendo poner el tamaño de papel en que vas a imprimir si es que es relavante, pues normalmente en este tipo de impresoras el número de caracteres al imprimir modo texto es limitado