# ¿Cómo imprimir usando Printable en Java?

Tags: java, print

Tengo una clase de impresión en Java y, lo que quiero hacer, es imprimir y personalizar el tamaño de una imagen que lo tengo en un `Label`. He intentado pasarle ese valor a Java `print`, pero al darle imprimir me genera una hoja en blanco.

Este es mi código:

```
private void BtnimprimirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                            
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    job.setPrintable(new Codigobarraplc());

    boolean doPrint = job.printDialog();
    System.out.println(doPrint);
    if (doPrint) {
        try {
            job.print();
        } catch (PrinterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

¿Cómo puedo pasarle el valor de esa etiqueta a Java `print`?

```
@Override
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws PrinterException
{
    if (page > 0) {
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }
    
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

    g2d.scale(pf.getImageableWidth() / this.getWidth(), pf.getImageableHeight() / this.getHeight());
    this.printAll(g2d);

    

    String text = lblImagen.getText();

    g.drawString(text, 100, 100);

    return PAGE_EXISTS;
}
```

Comment: Cual es el método Codigobarraplc() ?

Comment: @Jorgesys Codigobarraplc() es la clase donde está el metodo BtnimprimirActionPerformed ¿Cómo puedo pasarle solo el label para imprimir?

Comment: la imagen se indica en Codigobarraplc() , agrega este método.

Comment: Ese código me es extrañamente familiar :D

Answer (score 2):

En la línea

```
g2d.scale(pf.getImageableWidth() / this.getWidth(), pf.getImageableHeight() / this.getHeight());
```

estas usando una transformación afín como mencioné en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/232754/342) en este mismo sitio.

Como puedes leer en [la documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#scale(double,%20double)), internamente usa la matriz

```
[   sx   0    0   ]
[   0    sy   0   ]
[   0    0    1   ]
```

y la multiplica por toda la imagen que tenías produciendo una versión escalada. Los fundamentos matemáticos de esto los puedes hallar en cualquier curso de graficación por computadora que tenga el tema de transformaciones afines.

La relación entre el ancho del margen interno entre el ancho de la imagen nos indica a que escala horizontal está la imagen con respecto a la parte horizontal del margen.

La relación entre el alto del margen interno y la altura de la imagen nos indica a que escala vertical esta la imagen con respecto de la parte vertical del margen.

Usando esas proporciones como parámetro de la transformación afin lograremos que nuestra imágen se rescale cubriendo la totalidad del área de impresión tanto horizontal como verticalmente. Eso es lo que hace esa línea de código.

Basado en esto, si queremos que la imagen ocupe la tercera parte del ancho del margen de la hoja y la quinta de la altura del margen imprimible entiendo que haremos unos pocos calculos simples:

```
var anchoDeseado = pf.getImageableWidth()/3.0d;
var altoDeseado = pf.getImageableHeight()/5.0d;
g2d.scale(anchoDeseado / this.getWidth(), altoDeseado / this.getHeight());
```

No tengo tiempo de probarlo en este momento ya que es la 1 de la mañana donde vivo y mañana trabajo, pero espero esta respuesta te sea útil.

Si en vez de eso desearas imprimir tu label en su tamaño original deberás prmimero de obtener la coordenada del inicio del margen de impresión usando ImageableX e ImageableY, cosa que veo que ya haces.

Lo que veo que no has hecho es

```
lblImagen.printAll(g2d);
```

para que te renderice el texto e imagen que tuviera tu etiqueta en el área de impresión

Si deseas ahondar más en la teoría subyacente puedes consultar [este artículo](https://javapro.org/programming-languages/pageformat-configurar-impresion-en-java/) que escribí al respecto.

Answer (score 1):

Para imprimir imágenes contenidas en etiquetas Java, puede usar el método printAll() de la clase JLabel. Con este método, la imagen se imprime en la etiqueta. Para cambiar el tamaño de la imagen durante la impresión, puede usar el método scale() del objeto Graphics2D para establecer el tamaño deseado. El primer parámetro es el ancho y el segundo parámetro es la altura.

Por ejemplo, si desea imprimir la imagen en un tamaño de 200x200 píxeles, puede utilizar el siguiente código:

**g2d.scale(200.0 / this.getWidth(), 200.0 / this.getHeight());**

En tu caso, podría cambiar el código en el método print para que quede asi:

```
**g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
g2d.scale(200.0 / lblImagen.getWidth(), 200.0 / lblImagen.getHeight());
lblImagen.printAll(g2d);**
```

En resumen, para imprimir imágenes en una etiqueta, use el método **printAll()** de la clase JLabel. Para cambiar el tamaño de la imagen durante la impresión, utilice el método scale() del objeto Graphics2D para establecer el tamaño deseado.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución. Recuerda revisar https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido?cb=1 , Saludos..

Comment: @Jorgesys como sabes que lo escribio ChatGPT? si ese es el caso es baneable, literal quiere ganar recompensas por algo que él no escribió.

Comment: @infinit3Loop__ es muy sencillo detectarlo en casos como este, la misma respuesta te da indicios ya que chatGPT siempre te incluye la consulta que usa (por ejemplo aquí algo me dice que es imprimir imágenes contenidas en etiquetas Java) y otras cosas mas que por obvias razones no diré, puedes solicitar el baneo de la cuenta, pero en este caso Jorge le esta dando la oportunidad de responder en sus propias palabras antes de eso

Comment: @RuslanLopez de acuerdo gracias y no solicitare el baneo de nadie si ustedes no lo hacen.

Comment: @infinit3Loop__ yo creo que no es cosa de si hacerlo o no, sino de cuando hacerlo; no es que la respuesta este mal del todo, es que quien responde no sabe, no quiere o no puede explicar la solución, proveer fuentes de consulta, mostrar evidencia, o adaptar una solución empáticamente a quien pregunta. Cuando chatGPT pueda hacer estas cosas antes mencionadas seguramente se cambiará la política que lo restringe actualmente.

Comment: @MarcePuente no porque sea  etico es que se prohibió chatgpt sino porque requiere de mucha supervision de parte del que pregunta, por los posibles errores que puede generar(eso es lo que entiendo): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned

Comment: @Daniel Briceño, gracias por la aclaración, mi punto no es discutir los motivos de la prohiición, tratar de evitar falsas acusaciones, ya que considero que es muy difícil identificar su uso.